# Enable HTML5 in QtWebKit PyqQ5

Tags: youtube, html5-video, pyqt5, qtwebkit, youtube-dl

I'm trying to make a program which will download Youtube videos. It functions as it should, except that it doesn't support Youtube video playback. It seems to be an issue with html5 video support for QtWebKit.

If anyone can help me solve this problem, that would be appreciated.

Code can be found [here](https://github.com/voxelvortex/YoutubeDownloader)

(Being programmed in PyCharm on Windows 10 using the latest install of Anaconda)

Comment: Which version of PyQt5 are you using? `QtWebkit` support has been dropped for some time now in official `Qt` builds so you are likely using a very outdated version of WebKit. If you are up to the task of building `PyQt5` for yourself, I suggest you take a look at [this unofficial fork](https://github.com/annulen/webkit) of `QtWebKit`, which is being actively maintained. I just tested YouTube playback myself and it appears to work

Comment: After a bit more research I found out that youtube.com/v/<VidID>([example](https://www.youtube.com/v/R3AKlscrjmQ)) uses flash while youtube.com/watch?v=<VidID>([example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R3AKlscrjmQ)) uses html5. I could force the browser to use youtube.com/v/<VidID>, however, doing so would make navigating Youtube more difficult.

Comment: @user3419537 Thanks for commenting so quickly, how would I check what version I'm using?

Comment: You can grab the version string with `from PyQt5.QtCore import QT_VERSION_STR`, however if you're unsure, then chances are you have an official (old) build

Comment: According to a print statement related to the import `print(PYQT_VERSION_STR)` I've verified that I am running version 5.6

Comment: `QT_VERSION_STR` is what you want, not  `PYQT_VERSION_STR` as the `PyQt` version can differ from the version of `Qt` it was compiled against. Either way, you almost certainly have the old deprecated version of `QtWebKit` unless you or someone else built and installed `PyQt5` from source on your machine, as the official builds don't include it.

Comment: @VoxelVortexGaming. Why do you need to use QtWebKit? Why not use QtWebEngine?

Comment: @user3419537 I just checked again and it says `5.6.2` with `print(QT_VERSION_STR)`

Comment: @ekhumoro I don't seem to have that included with my install of PyQt

[See here](http://imgur.com/a/dv5tC)

Comment: I reinstalled PyQt5 and  now I am using PyQt5.9. I'll move ahead with QtWebEngine and see if it works out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QtWebKit doesn't seem to support HTML5 video, I have decided to try out QtWebEngine.

Comment: Yeah, it works like a charm :) (you can check out my program [here](https://github.com/voxelvortex/YoutubeDownloader/tree/NewProg))

Comment: Thanks for the link! Your program looks great! What version of PyQt5 includes `QtWebEngine`? It seems, on Anaconda 5.5.1 is the latest available update. I think you need PyQt5.9, right? If so, how did you install 5.9 on Conda?

Comment: In order to use 5.9 w/ anaconda you have to uninstall pyqt5 with pip and reinstall it; Conda is kind of annoying because it only uses it's own distributions of libraries, so you don't always get the latest version.



tldr; Something like
`pip uninstall pyqt5`
`pip install pyqt5` should fix the issue